# Adding text to a file

Tags: document-library, update

Is there a way to add Document ID in the footer area of a word file? This can be workflow to update a new word file. User will either upload or create new word file in a document library (doc id enabled). After the file is saved to the document library i would like to update the document with the document id via workflow. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a Word Template and use it as the default Content Type for the library.

Inside the template you can use Quick Parts for populating list fields. In your case you can add the document ID as a meta data property and then use it in the quick part.

Here is a complete walk through http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, Document ID field does not show up in the document properties list. http://blogs.technet.com/photos/brenclarke/images/3226717/original.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This link helped. It's little tricky but all steps are well defined.

http://blog.isaacblum.com/2011/02/28/add-document-id-to-word-document-automatically/